# Как из битрикса с получить все сделки, а не только первые 50?

Tags: php, битрикс

Может кто объяснить, как на php из битрикса вытащить все сделки, а не только первые 50 ? Мучаюсь уже третий день, в сети что-то нашел, но ничего не понял. Пожалуйста, кто в состоянии, объясните.

Comment: Мы тоже ничего не поняли

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я через апи битрикса хочу получить все сделки с портала, использую метод crm.deal.list, но он мне выдает только первые 50 сделок и вот как мне получить все сделки, которые у меня есть в портале, а там их примерно 10к

Comment: Потому что GET запрос может принять только 50шт. Походу ты через file_get_contents() это делаешь.
Что бы все принять надо просто через curl получать.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть у вас в запросе стоит "nPageSize"=>50?

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(
Array(), 
$arFilter, 
false, 
Array("nPageSize"=>50), 
$arSelect
);
```

Тогда поставьте false